# Changing an output for a link in php

Tags: php, authentication, href, logout

I'm trying to get a link in my menu to change once the user logged in. Meaning that "My Page" is displayed, rather than "Log In". Now, the user can log in and log out. Yet the name/link will not change directly after the user logged in.

My code for the menu: (I use include('menu.php' on all sites. For flexibility of the code)

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><?php echo $mypage?></li>
    <li><a href="community.html">Community</a></li>
    <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

My code for the config.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

$mypage;

if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
$mypage = '<a href="mypage.php">My Page</a>';
}
else {
    $mypage = '<a href="login.php">Log In</a>';
}
?>
```

Only when the user clicks on another menu the $mypage variable will update. I've tried refreshing the page with a header() function. But this only lead into a redirection-loop.

It would be great if someone could help me out.

**EDIT**

To clear some things up:

For a better understanding of the website:
[http://www.askmephilosophy.camilstaps.nl/](http://askmephilosophy.camilstaps.nl/)
(The only thing that can be viewed (so far) are the 'Welcome' and 'Log In'. After a login you will be redirected to a mypage.php site. (this can also be accessed by just typing it after the name. */mypage.php)

Comment: Do you handle the login before or after you include `config.php`? The execution order is probably wrong.

Comment: How does your login script works? If it sets the session without refreshing, most likely nothing will happen on the page. It's like opening your browser cookies and set session cookie `name` to something. A refresh will be needed everytime.

Comment: Can you show how you included the files?

Comment: <?php
include('config.php');
?>

On my login.php I use:
    <?php
    require_once('config.php');
    include('session.php');
    ?>

In this session.php script the password is hashed, checked with the password in the database and once that is okay:

if( $hash == $r['Password'] ) {
 $_SESSION['name'] = $username;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand: 
1/ you log-in
2/ you are logged but the name stay "Log In"
3/ you refresh the page then the menu changes to "My Page"

I think that you set $_SESSION['name'] **AFTER** you execute this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $mypage = '<a href="mypage.php">My Page</a>';
}
else {
    $mypage = '<a href="login.php">Log In</a>';
}
```

Try something like this:

```
if (isset ($_POST['name']) && isset ($_POST['password']) && ($_POST['password'] == $hash)) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
}
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $mypage = '<a href="mypage.php">My Page</a>';
} else {
    $mypage = '<a href="login.php">Log In</a>';
}
```

Comment: That might be the case, I don't know.
Should I include in this:

if( $hash == $r['Password'] ) {
 $_SESSION['name'] = $username;
}

a require_once('config.php')?

Comment: and don't forget to add session_start(); at the top of your code

Comment: Some sad news, it's still not working. I will not be able to respond immediately, as I'm going on a trip to Rome with my school. I will be staying there for a week.